# faultStrg:Send failed faultDetail:Channel.Connect.Fail error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: http:/ex.com/flex2gateway/

Tags: ssl, apache-flex, coldfusion-11

We are upgrading our ColdFusion 9 non-ssl application to ColdFusion 11 ssl enabled setup using Websphere.

We have a few flex components that utilize Flex2Gateway to call remote services. The application/Flex2gateway calls work fine with http but not on https. I get the following error when accessing the flex component with only https enabled.

```
faultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend faultString:'Send failed' faultDetail:'Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'http://locations-dev.hban.us/flex2gateway/''
```

I am not sure what triggers the http request within the flex component, there is no hardcoding for sure.

Here is my remoting-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service id="remoting-service" 
class="flex.messaging.services.RemotingService" 
messageTypes="flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage">

<adapters>
<adapter-definition id="cf-object" 
class="coldfusion.flash.messaging.ColdFusionAdapter" default="true"/>
<adapter-definition id="java-object" 
class="flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter"/>
</adapters>

<default-channels>
<channel ref="my-cfamf-secure"/>
</default-channels>

 <destination id="ColdFusion">
  <channels>
    <channel ref="my-cfamf-secure"/>
</channels>
<properties>
    <source>*</source>
</properties>
</destination>
```

Comment: This remoting config is on your server, not your local CF installation, right? Check if you have the my-cfamf-secure channel description in your services-config as well. What happens if you set the channel to my-cfamf but still set https as the endpoint for the service (this is how it is set in one of my projects). And last but not least - are you sure the server is accepting https request (any restrictions, ports?)

Comment: @Philarmon Verified all your questions and everything is configured right. I get the same error when I set https as the endpoint for the service. Also, the rest of the application works fine with https. The only thing that confuses me is that the flex component invokes http request rather than https. Not sure how that gets invoked. Any ideas?

Comment: what does your services-config.xml say? are you compiling against the right file?